# Gnome-panel white vertical lines between minimized apps

Tags: gnome-panel, themes

When I minimize programs to gnome-panel, I now have white vertical lines separating them, this never used to happen.

[image: Close up]

[image: Embed image]

I have tried deleting my .gconf, .metacity, .gnome2 folders, re-installing light themes, nothing seems to work.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Try refreshing your panel by entering this command in your terminal `killall gnome-panel`

Comment: After updating to 11.04 this is still persisting, very annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This normally happens if compiz has stopped working or if you are using metacity its composting is turned off.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I ended up switching to docky for a slightly cleaner desktop.